# Delete objects from array in state using unique ID

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, html-framework-7

I have list which elements must be deletable (for example with delete button). How can I realize that from react?

this is my state:

```
state = {
        infos: [
            {
                id: 1,
                info: 'some info',
                deleted: false
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                info: 'some info',
                deleted: false
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                info: 'some info',
                deleted: false
            }
        ]
    }
```

this is a function for delete that I tried:

```
removeInfo() {
  this.state.infos.splice(key, 0)
}
```

this is a jsx code that I get after maping:

```
{
                      this.state.infos.map((item, key) => {
                          return (
                              <ListItem key={item.key + key}>
                                  <Icon color="gray" f7="home" />
                                  <span className="text-black">{item.info}</span>
                                  <Button><Icon f7="edit" color="#39b549" /></Button>
                                  <Button onClick={this.removeInfo}><Icon color="black" f7="trash" /></Button>
                              </ListItem>
                          )
                      })
                  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need few changes.

First we need to pass the id of item we want to remove to the remove function:

```
 <Button onClick={()=>this.removeInfo(item.id)}><Icon color="black" f7="trash" /></Button>
```

Then you need to remove the item from array in immutable way using `setState`.

```
removeInfo(id) {
  this.setState(ps=>({infos:ps.infos.filter(x=>x.id!=id)}))
}
```

`splice` mutates the array.

Comment: Thank You very much it was the shortest and simplest solution!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use setState and note that you can´t mutate the state so you need to use the spread operator to create a new array.

```
function removeInfo(index) {
  this.setState((prev) => ({
    infos: [...prev.infos.slice(0, index), ...prev.infos.slice(index+1)]
  }))
}
```

Comment: Your answer was helpful too. Thank You for help